# Performance comparison of LinkedblockingQueue in real time environment

Tags: java, performance, queue

I am using LinkedBlockingQueue with capacity 1000

**LinkedBlockingQueue sQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(1000);**

**LinkedBlockingQueue rQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue;**

Files which needs to be compressed are put in the sQueue and received from rQueue.

Recently i am getting an exception from time to time but occurrences are less.

On analyzing i found that probably the **bounded LinkedBlockingQueue (sQueue)** is causing the problem.

Basically I would like to know whether there will be any performance issue or rather memory increase if i use unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue OR by increasing the capacity to 2000?
and if so by how much?

As it's a live system i need to make sure that this change will not cause any large impact.

Comment: This change may cause large impact, because queue can grow till Integer's max value, which is very high that 1000.

Comment: But again LinkedBlockingQueue grows dynamically right?or bounded queue size will be set at integer's max value on initialization and memory usage will be high?

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue grows dynamically, the given cpacity has no impact on memory usage at initialization. See also the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#LinkedBlockingQueue.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29).